SABR parameter fitting to ATM normal vol in Quantlib
I’m trying to fit SABR parameters to implied normal vols of options on interest rate futures. I’m attempting this using Quantlib in Python.
This link
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/fininst/calibrating-the-sabr-model.html
Explains two methods to calibrate parameters; the second optimises for $\rho$ and $\nu$ and $\alpha$ is solved using ATM vol
I’m trying to attempt this using quantlib specifically in Python
My method is

to use quantlibs SafeSABRInterpolation to vary $\alpha$ $\nu$ $\rho$ and fit to data

solve for the $\alpha$ which gives ATM vol given the $\rho$ and $\nu$ calculated in (1)

keep $\alpha$ fixed and vary $\rho$ and $\nu$ to find optimal parameters for $\rho$ and $\nu$


Now im not getting a good fit by doing this although it makes sense. I understand there’s a limitation in that the objective function should really be solving for $\alpha$ at every iteration of $\rho$ and $\nu$ but is there a way to do this in quantlib?

What data are you using? A big limitation in calibrating surfaces and models is good data. If you’re using equities quotes, it may struggle due to wide spreads. Most papers will use FX quotes since spreads are tighter so it’s easier to get reasonable results. Some derivatives markets can be very illiquid and it’s not feasible nor reasonable to calibrate a model to it
